# Adding a legend for many subfloats: unlabeled subfloat

Tags: numbering, memoir, subfloats

I am using `memoir` and adding `subbottom` to `figure` environments like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\subbottom[Blah......]
{
First figure
}
\subbottom
{
Legend goes here
}
\subbottom[Blah.....]
{
Second figure
}
\end{figure}
```

How do I make it so that the legend subfigure does not use up a letter so that the first and second real figures get labeled 1.a) and 1.b) (rather than 1.c)?

I considered letting the legend be part of one of the existing figures, but it creates an imbalance that I don't like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually correct the counter:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subbottom[Blah......]
{%
First figure
}%
\subbottom
{%
Legend goes here
}%
\addtocounter{subfigure}{-1}%
\subbottom[Blah.....]
{%
Second figure
}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]